# knit HTML does not save html in vignettes/

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

So I have a vignette, `vignettes/test-vignette3.Rmd`:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: kate
    theme: spacelab
    toc: yes
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---

Header
=========
```

When I hit the `knit HTML` button, I get the following:

```
processing file: test-vignette3.Rmd
output file: test-vignette3.knit.md


Output created: /tmp/RtmpKVpegL/preview-5ef42271c0d5.dir/test-vignette3.html
```

However, if I copy this file to `inst/doc` and hit the `knit HTML` button, I get:

```
processing file: test-vignette3.Rmd
output file: test-vignette3.knit.md


Output created: test-vignette3.html
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get RStudio to save the output from `knit HTML` on `vignettes/test-vignette3.Rmw` to the vignettes directory?
2. How do I get RStudio to not delete `test-vignette3.knit.md` during the `knit HTML` procedure? (I'd like to have the .md so people can read it on my github repo.)

I'm running RStudio version 0.98.836, rmarkdown version 0.1.98 and knitr version 1.5.

Answer (score 9):

Actually you should *not* keep the .html output under `vignettes/`, because the vignette output is supposed to be generated by `R CMD build`. R may fail to recompile your vignettes if the HTML output files have already been there when you build the source package, which means you are likely to see old (and possibly wrong) results because the HTML file was not generated from the latest version of the `.Rmd` file. Therefore RStudio intentionally avoid writing the HTML files in the vignetttes directory.

If you choose to ignore the warning above, you can certainly run `rmarkdown::render('your-vignette.Rmd')` in the R console.

For the second question, I do not recommend you to do that, either, because Github renders the markdown to HTML differently (compared to the Pandoc conversion done through the **rmarkdown** package). Normally the package vignettes are shown on CRAN, see, for example, [the knitr page](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=knitr) on CRAN. However, because the rmarkdown package is not on CRAN yet, you cannot use the vignette engine `knitr::rmarkdown` at the moment (I guess we are not too far away from the CRAN release now). You can consider pushing the HTML files to Github pages, though.

Comment: This is very logical, but it is also very surprising to the user. It took me several days before I found this answer and realised why my knitr vignettes were mysteriously not appearing in 'vignettes'. It might be better to have consistent behaviour and to do something different only when building the package.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing I can do on my side. The behavior is defined by R core. If you use RStudio, RStudio will not actually generate the html file when you click the Knit button. If you other editors, we cannot help.

Comment: Well, this is an RStudio issue. I'm fine with `rmarkdown::render`, which does just what it says and will happily generate HTML inside vignettes. The question is whether the knit button should behave specially inside a vignette directory. My view would be, if you are building a CRAN package, your build process probably shouldn't involve manually clicking the knit button - it should involve e.g. `devtools::build_vignettes`. And OTOH the knit button should do what I expect.

Comment: I am surprised this answer is not accepted. Anyways - it's very useful. Thanks, but more importantly thanks for you great packages