# using rmarkdown as a vignette engine

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I've written a few vignettes in R Markdown, with the intention of having them
get built with RStudio's [rmarkdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown)
package. I know that `rmarkdown::render` is the function we use to convert
.rmd's to .html (or whatever other format), however, when I place

```
<!--
%\VignetteEnginer{rmarkdown::render}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{some test title}
-->
```

in the preamble of my .rmd (and `knitr` and `rmarkdown` in my Suggest's field of
DESCRIPTION, as well as `rmarkdown` in the VignetteBuilder field) my vignette
does not compile.

Has anyone managed to get `rmarkdown` to act as a vignette builder?

Answer (score 10):

Taking from @Ben's answer (and the comments below), `knitr` *has* registered a vignette engine that accesses `rmarkdown` (if it's installed) and

```
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Supplementary materials}
-->
```

is example of how we'd register it. However, in order to take full advantage of `rmarkdown` (that is, conversion of `.Rmd`'s into `.html`'s and preservation of any styling defined in the `.Rmd`) you must place the code snippet above ***BELOW*** the "rmarkdown preamble". As an example, the top of your `.Rmd` should look like

```
---
Title: "Supplementary Materials"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
---
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Supplementary Materials}
-->
```

Of course, you also need to make sure you have appropriately created your DESCRIPTION file to include `rmarkdown` and `knitr`. The simplest way to do this is with

```
Suggests: knitr, rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: I feel very confused with this because `knitr::rmarkdown` indeed does not exist. I came up with the same solution going line by line in debuging mode but don't understand it

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use `rmarkdown` rather than `knitr`? At first glance your question looks like a bit of confusion between `rmarkdown` and `knitr`. To clarify:

[`rmarkdown`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) is an 'authoring format' that is 'based on knitr and pandoc'. When we run `rmarkdown::render` we are calling `knitr` and/or pandoc.

[`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/) is the engine that converts rmarkdown to html/PDF/docx. This is what is executing the `R` code to get output and plots and so on.

The `knitr` package author [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23693519/1036500) that 'because the rmarkdown package is not on CRAN yet, you cannot use the vignette engine knitr::rmarkdown at the moment'. If you can't wait you could [register your own engine](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Non_002dSweave-vignettes) but that looks rather complex.

I think what you want is:

This at the top of your Rmd doc:

```
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Supplementary materials}
-->
```

And this in your `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests:
    knitr
```

For a complete example, check out the [`tidyr` package](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/), here's the [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) and here's the [rmarkdown vignette](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/vignettes/tidy-data.Rmd) (hat-tip to [Andrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602276/andrie) for pointing me to this).

If there's something specific you want from `rmarkdown` that you can't get from `knitr` (a custom style, etc.) then you should put that up in a new question.

Comment: This uses `knitr` to compile the vignettes, not `rmarkdown` (the RStudio package linked to above)...

Comment: I've made some edits to my answer, seems like you might need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I think, at the end of the day, I wanted to register an engine using `rmarkdown` explicitly. However, looking into how `knitr` registers its engines, it actually appears that, _if `rmarkdown` is present_, `knitr::rmarkdown` will call the package during its vignette building routine. The only thing that baffles me, now, is why my vignette's lose their styling, upon compilation...

Comment: Yes that's a good question about document styling. Can you ask it as a new question with a self-contained example? That will attract more attention and hopefully a good answer.

Comment: Turns out, they don't lose their styling if you make sure to put the markdown preamble _before_ the vignette preamble. I'll explain this is a separate answer.